# Fibonacci-related infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, theta-functions

Prove that
 $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\theta_2^2\bigg(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2n+1}+F_{2k-1}}=\frac{(2k-1)\sqrt{5}}{2F_{2k-1}}$$
Where  $\theta(z,\tau)$ is the Jacobi theta function.

An interesting fact about  this series is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2n+1}}$ is transcendental and  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2n+1}+1}$ is algebraic.

Comment: Not completely unrelated : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51426/reciprocals-of-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: For the first, [this](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/fibon-tifr.pdf) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html) give a reference to an article of Edmund Landau which is [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1899__27_/BSMF_1899__27__297_0/BSMF_1899__27__297_0.pdf) pp. 298-300 (in french).